# Do we need different Presenter for Login as well as Signup Activity in android MVP pattern?

Tags: android, design-patterns, android-mvp, presenter

I am implementing MVP design architecture in my android application. I am new to design patterns and haven't use any in my previous project. I want to know that whether we need different presenters for different activities such as let's say,  Login and Sign up, or just one presenter handling both activities. If yes, then please guide me through this process and a sample code with folder structure will be very helpful. Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

I've just implemented an MVP app with this two screens, one for login and one for sign up or register, both of they are activitys.

Yes, you can use one single presenter for many diferents views but the poing of using MVP or another presentation layer is making the views independents from the logic and in my opinion independets to make it easier of using tests.

In my case I did one view and presenter diferents for each activity.

Here you can find a basic explanation of the MVP:  https://antonioleiva.com/mvp-android/